# Is it adequate to ask for hints about how to build projects on this site?

Tags: discussion, support

Sometimes I have a project in mind, I know what it's going to do but I'm not really sure on how to build it yet. Is it adequate to ask for tips about *ways* for this project to be done?

Comment: Do you mean: are questions about organizing a large project into many notebooks and packages welcome on _Mathematica_ .SE?

Comment: Nope. I mean: I have some projects but I have no idea on where I should start for making them, is it adequate to ask about it here?

Comment: Probably not, because in all likelihood, your problem is localized to your project and not necessarily a _Mathematica_ question. I don't think the fact that it will eventually be written/implemented in _Mathematica_ is reason enough to ask questions that require significant domain expertise.

Comment: @rm-rf I think this very much depends on the specific question. Some larger-scale aspects of project organization and architecture can be very intimately tied with Mathematica specifics, since each language provides its own set of tools to scale the code base and deal with larger projects. I also think that this type of questions and aswers to them may be useful for the community. The problem really seems to be in where to draw a line between these and the other type of questions, which you probably had in mind.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I fully agree with you, and I've also publicly stated my support for that (deleted, but you can [see it here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/744/migration-proposals-from-stackoverflow-to-mathematica-se/951#comment4153_951). The rest are probably somewhere in chat, and am too lazy to search now). As for this question, Gustavo didn't give any indication of what kinds of projects he had in mind, and from his comment above as a reply to m_goldberg, it's clear his interest was not in the architecture/organization aspects of it, but rather "where should I start".

Comment: (contd..) I took that to mean he wants to know how and where to start _his specific projects_, which is localized (and probably needs domain expertise, depending on the project).

Comment: @rm-rf I don't disagree, and I don't have a very strong opinion on the matter. I actually think that even somewhat localized projects can be interesting in this respect, because of some Mathematica (and general) design patterns one may employ there.  My point really was that there isn't IMO a general answer here, but that there are at least some project-related questions which may be on-topic for us.